# uniqueIdentifier find in .xcodeproj. how to remove it

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, uniqueidentifier

When i execute this command  grep -ir "uniqueIdentifier" . then found one match.
Binary file ./proj1.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/usser1.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches
Because of this match i am not able to upload this binary on appstore.
i am not using any non-public API.

When i try to validate then organizer show issue screen with below issues.
*your app contains non-public API usage. please review the error, correct then and resubmit your Application.
Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the
* UniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice.please update youy apps and servers to associate user with the vendor or asverstising identifies introduction in ios6. if you think this message was sent in errorand that you have only user apple-published API's in accordance with the guidelines, send the app's nini-digit apple id, along with detailed information about why you believe the above API's were incorrectly flagged, to appreview@apple.com. for further information, visit the Technical Support information page at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by the error message shown by Organizer, you must not use `uniqueIdentifier`

Search for `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` in your code. You must be using this method somewhere. If you can not find it, then it might be one of your libraries are using this deprecated method.

Use the search feature in Xcode at the top left corner, the third tab, or Cmd+Shift+F (find in Workspace) to find the problematic files:

[image: Search for uniqueIdentifier]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error from MKStoreKit's VerificationController files.  Chances are there's a chunk of code using the now obsolete uniqueIdentifier code. Apple provides a link for changing any lines you yourself have written using this code, but if you didn't use this code it's probably in a store kit or a rating kit code you've gotten somewhere.

Do what I always do: hack out files that you didn't yourself write and see which one is causing the problem, then go from there.

Comment: Is there any way to edit a compiled static library (.a file) that includes calls to uniqueIdentifier, @redux?  I am using a third party file, and there is no updated version...